# Cloning conda "root", if that is the term for your basic initial install

Tags: anaconda, environment, conda, miniconda

There seem to be other similar questions, but none that seem to be exactly this.

I have created a conda install on a machine. I want to create the exact same install on a 2nd machine. I could export the environment and then create an environment using that exported information. But in all the examples, I'm creating an *environment* that is a clone of the root. Not a new root that is a clone of the root.

So how to I create a true clone of a conda install? The idea would be

1. Export the environment of the root on machine 1

   `conda [something...] > configuration.yml`
2. Install miniconda using `Miniconda....sh` on machine 2
3. Recreate the original environment

   `conda [install all the stuff including enironments] configuration.yml`

I can't seem to find any explicit instructions for doing this. The [closest I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702703/188963) suggests:

```
conda env export > environment.yml              
conda env update -n root -f environment.yml
```

However the first command draws an error:

```
balter@server:/home/.../Applications$ conda env export > environment.yml


CondaEnvException: Conda Env Exception: Unable to determine environment

Please re-run this command with one of the following options:

* Provide an environment name via --name or -n
* Re-run this command inside an activated conda environment.


balter@server:/home/.../Applications$ conda -h
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.

Options:

...
...
```

[One of the posts](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/OlFk6HbC57E) I found on the interwebs discusses two points that I'm unclear about:

1) Whether pip installs also carry over, and
2) The difference between

```
conda env create
```

and

```
conda create
```

Comment: The first error seems pretty clear... provide a name for the environment you want to export, e.g., `root`.

Comment: Yes, that does work. However, even the docs say that what I typed should work. Try typing `conda env export -h`. The two examples given are exactly what I have in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conda environments exist as an [easy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42101695/5049524) to this sort of problem. However, it is possible to do what you ask.

Step 1: confirm you are in the root environment on the first machine, then export a list of the installed packages:

```
$ source activate root
$ conda list -e > root.yml
```

Step 2: on the other machine, download and install [Miniconda](http://conda.io/miniconda.html), then install the packages from `root.yml`:

```
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ conda install --file root.yml
```

Comment: Oh golly, that is simple. I know all the steps except for the last! I didn't know that conda could install from a file created by conda list.